# Django:How do I put the initial data into the database before Migrate?

Tags: python, django, database, migrate

Added models from existing code.
I'd like to put in the initial data when I migrate the models I've added.

> python3 -m pip install sqlparse
>
> python3 manage.py makeemigations sbimage

//I have edited the generated 0002 file.

> python3 manage.py Migrate image 0002

//Normal operation confirmed.

> python3 manage.py sqlmigrate thimage 0002

//Normal operation confirmed.

However, the data did not enter the table when the database was verified.

```
from django.db import migrations, models

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('sbimage', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='AuthNumberR',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('auth_number_r', models.CharField(max_length=64)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.RunSQL("INSERT INTO AuthNumberR (id, auth_number_r) VALUES (2, 'c');"),
    ]
```

Comment: I think Django will create table with name something like "appName_tableName". Did you verified running that insert sql manually ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [django fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/initial-data/#providing-data-with-fixtures) to provide initial data to your database. It is quite useful for your case.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not use naked SQL queried, instead try using something like this

```
from django.db import migrations

def combine_names(apps, schema_editor):
    # We can't import the Person model directly as it may be a newer
    # version than this migration expects. We use the historical version.
    Person = apps.get_model('yourappname', 'Person')
    for person in Person.objects.all():
        person.name = '%s %s' % (person.first_name, person.last_name)
        person.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('yourappname', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(combine_names),
    ]
```

Reference : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/#data-migrations