# raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.") django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, json, django, api, sqlite

this is django rest_framework api I created this api for restourant. This is menu api . I want to save menu.json's data to my database, but I could not. Can you give any advice to save json data to my models. I got this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\OSMAN MERT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 49, in __get__     
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\OSMAN MERT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 113, in related_model
    apps.check_models_ready()
  File "C:\Users\OSMAN MERT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 143, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

models.py

```
class Meal(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_vegetarian = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_vegan = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    #groups = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    #meal = models.ForeignKey(Meal, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ingredients')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Option(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    quality = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    per_amount = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class MealIngredient(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    meal = models.ForeignKey(Meal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)



path = r"C:\Users\OSMAN MERT\Desktop\menu\menu_core\menu.json"

with open(path) as f:
  data = json.loads(f.read())

for meal in data["meals"]:
    id = meal["id"]
    name = meal["name"]
    meal_obj, created = Meal.objects.get_or_create(name=name)
    for ingredient in meal["ingredients"]:
        name_in = ingredient["name"]
        ingredient_obj, created = Ingredient.objects.get_or_create(name=name_in)
        MealIngredient.objects.get_or_create(meal=meal_obj, ingredient=ingredient_obj)

for ingre in data["ingredients"]:
  ingre_name = ingre["name"]
  ingre_obj, created = Ingredient.objects.get_or_create(name=ingre_name)

  for opti in ingre["options"]:
    opt_name = opti["name"]
    opt_quality = opti["quality"]
    opt_price = opti["price"]
    opt_amount = opti["per_amount"]
    Option.objects.get_or_create(ingredient=ingre_obj, name=opt_name, quality=opt_quality,
                                  price=opt_price, per_amount=opt_amount)
```

This is some data from menu.json not all code include there. menu.json

```
{
    "meals": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Rice and chicken bowl",
        "ingredients": [
          { "name": "Rice", "quantity": 120, "quantity_type": "gram" },
          { "name": "Chicken", "quantity": 85, "quantity_type": "gram" }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Pasta with marinara sauce and vegetables",
        "ingredients": [
          { "name": "Pasta", "quantity": 115, "quantity_type": "gram" },
          {
            "name": "Marinara sauce",
            "quantity": 120,
            "quantity_type": "millilitre"
          },
          { "name": "Vegetables", "quantity": 240, "quantity_type": "gram" }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Grilled chicken with roasted vegetables",
        "ingredients": [
          { "name": "Chicken", "quantity": 85, "quantity_type": "gram" },
          { "name": "Vegetables", "quantity": 240, "quantity_type": "gram" }
        ]
      }
    ],
  
    "ingredients": [
      {
        "name": "Rice",
        "groups": ["vegan", "vegetarian"],
        "options": [
          {
            "name": "Long grain white rice",
            "quality": "high",
            "price": 3,
            "per_amount": "kilogram"
          },
          {
            "name": "Medium grain brown rice",
            "quality": "medium",
            "price": 2,
            "per_amount": "kilogram"
          },
          {
            "name": "Quick cooking white rice",
            "quality": "low",
            "price": 1.5,
            "per_amount": "kilogram"
          }
        ]
      }]
```

Comment: Why are you running that code to create items in the database inside your models.py file? That is not an appropriate place to do that, models might be loaded even before migrations are performed. You can either use fixtures or data migrations for this purpose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Providing initial data for models - Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54958008/providing-initial-data-for-models-django) also [Django:How do I put the initial data into the database before Migrate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56882377/djangohow-do-i-put-the-initial-data-into-the-database-before-migrate)

Comment: I  deleted all thing except models but it gives me no such column: api_ingredient.meal_id

Comment: can you give example how to apply  fixtures or data migrations